# conditional promise in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to call conditional promise without nested promise and execute the rest of the code irrespective whether condition statisfy or not

```
        findAllByServiceProviderLocationId(serviceProviderLocationId, supplierId)
    .then(result => {
    // 1. set all the default values
    ChargesAdminController._setDefaultValues(result);
    //Based on some condition in result - i need to call new promise
    //If condition satisfy, do promise operation and continue executing. is there better way to do apart from nested promise`enter code here`
    //Ex:
    if(result.checkPricing){
        DBConnection.getPricing(result)
     }
        //some operations on result object before sending response - All these operations should run only after the conditional promise is fulfilled 
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of logic is simplest with `async/await` because you can write more traditional sequential code flow logic.

```
async function myFunc() {
    let result = await someFunc1();
    if (result.whatever === something) {
         // asynchronous operation inside the if statement
         await someFunc2();
    }
    // code here that gets executed regardless of the above if
    let someOtherResult = await someFunc3();
    return someResult;
}
```

Without `async/await` you do have to do some nesting, but only for the conditional:

```
function myFunc() {
    return someFunc1().then(result => {
        if (result.whatever === something) {
            // asynchronous operation inside the if statement
            return someFunc2();
        } else {
            return somethingElse;
        }
    }).then(thing => {
        // code here that gets executed regardless of the above if statement
        return someFunc3();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. One small question in if block we are returning a promise which will be handled in next then block. Is it possible to just send object in else instead of promise?

Comment: @PhaniKumar - I don't know what "just send object in else instead of promise" means?

Comment: I mean to just return object in else blank.. Like return result; in else where as promise in if block like.. Dbconnection.getPrices(). Do we need to use Bluebird. Resolve() in else?

Comment: @PhaniKumar - See my 2nd code example.  Inside a `.then()` handler, it's perfectly OK to return a promise in the `if` and a value in the `else`.  That's exactly what my example does.  In the `else`, the value becomes the resolved value of the chain.  In the `if`, the eventual resolved value of the promise you return becomes the resolved value of the chain.  Both are perfectly allowed.